# How to make a type an instance of Eq

Tags: haskell, instance, typeclass

I have a data type called `Praat`. I want `Praat` to be an instance of `Eq` so that two `Praat`s are equal if and only if `mx` are equal.  How does one do this?

```
-- data type
data Praat t = Praat [k] [(k,k,k,k)] 

-- praat gives the maximum frequency
Praat t -> Int
mx (Praat [] _) = 0
mx (Praat (e:es) pt) = ...........
```

This is how I am trying to define the instance but it is not working.

```
-- I want to make Praat instance of Eq so that two Praat are equal
-- when their respective `mx` are equal
instance Eq Praat where
   mx :: (Praat k)->Int
   (mx k) == (mx k) = True
   _ == _ = False
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
instance Eq Praat where
    x == y = mx x == mx y
```

This is pretty much a direct translation of what you said. `x` is equal to `y` when `mx x == mx y`.

Comment: I'd even write it `(==) 'on' mx`